# Energy of a permanent magnet railgun

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

I'm creating a permanent magnet railgun, which essentially uses two conducting rods with a row of magnets between them and a conducting projectile laying across the two rods. I am trying to determine the efficiency of this setup, so I would like to calculate the total theoretical energy going in to making the projectile move.

Without the permanent magnets, the railgun does not go, so I am assuming the Lorentz force from the railgun rods is negligible. Does this mean that all of the work is being done by the magnetic field from the permanent magnets? How do I calculate theoretical energy? Can I use work by multiplying the magnetic force by the distance over which the projectile accelerates in the magnetic field?

Comment: It would help if you provided a diagram because it's not clear how you are orienting the magnets and their poles with respect to the rest of the railgun.

Answer (score 2):

The work is being done by the current you are forcing through the rod. If there is no magnetic field, there is no back e.m.f. when the rod starts to move (because there's no $\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$). As the magnetic field gets stronger, the Lorentz force due to the interaction of current with magnetic field becomes greater. This is what pushes the rod down the gun - and the work done is entirely electrical (the magnets end up with the same magnetic field after the gun is fired).

You can calculate the energy a couple of different ways.

Obviously, the energy you put in (barring losses) should be equal to the kinetic energy of the projectile. That should be equal to the electrical energy put in: that is, the work done by forcing the current against the back emf of the rods - induced by the motion of the rod in the magnetic field.

If the magnetic field is a constant $B$ perpendicular to the rails, and the spacing of the rails is $d$, then for a velocity $v$ the change in flux is

$$V = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt} = -B\frac{dA}{dt} = -Bvd$$

And with a given current $I$, the instantaneous power is

$$P = VI = IBvd$$

You can integrate this over time to get the total energy:

$$E = \int P\cdot dt = IB\ell d$$

since $\int v\cdot dt = \ell$, the length of the rail gun.

This shows that if you use constant current, the voltage (and thus the power) increases with the velocity of the projectile - this is why rail guns can reach such high velocities over a short rail (with sufficiently high current source and strong magnet).